# How can I use graphLoader from another program ,and get result success or failure

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I run graphLoader in console But I would like an autonmatic process to call graphLoader and be able to know if graphLoader succeeded or fails .and which vertexes and edges failed on insert in case of error.(Is graphLoader success means all data inserted and failure means ,The whole loading fails ?)

Answer (score 0):

have you seen the graph loader logs?  Do the logs provide the information you're looking for with this item?